# Android samples - Accelerometer and APIDemos do not build

Tags: android

I am new to Android development. I have succesfully installed eclipse with Android Developer Tool plugin and many of the samples work fine.

But Android samples - `Accelerometer and APIDemos do not build`. I see many build errors notifying to fix the errors in code. I dont think Google has released APIDemo sample with build errors.

Thanks in advance, please advice how to fix these errors, or if any configuration/setting is required.

I have set the Java compiler compliance level to 1.6.

Error information(for acceralometer sample):

The project contains error(s) in application. Please fix them before running

```
Error details:

    The method onAccuracyChanged(Sensor, int) of type AccelerometerPlayActivity.SimulationView must override a superclass method    
    AccelerometerPlayActivity.java  /AccelerometerPlay/src/com/example/android/accelerometerplay    line 456    
    Java Problem
    Call requires API level 8 (current min is 5): 
    android.view.Display#getRotation    AccelerometerPlayActivity.java  /AccelerometerPlay/src/com/example/android/accelerometerplay    
    line 389    Android Lint Problem
```

Regards,
Jai

Answer (score 1):

Look for the line `androidminSdkVersion ="5"` in your android.manifest file

and change its value from `5 to 8` or anything more than `8`

[image]

Alternative is
Go to `project` `properties` by *right clicking* on you project,
thereafter look for `Android` in properties.
You have to select the `build target` here `equivalent to the api` for which it the sample project is build for

Refer Image[image]

Say if you are using the sample from folder `android-12` then you have to check the same option(ie `API Level 12`) here in properties

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason can be a slow PC, which does not build in time. Then errors occur due to absence of R.java

In that case (errors are with something like `R.id.stuff`), build the project and wait.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix myself!

Earlier I tried with Andriod version 4.0. Now I just tried ApiDemos sample with Android version 4.1.2. It worked fine. I also deployed the apk in my mobile. It just works fine.

Comment: thats not the solution.. What you did is just used the new version of same project whic actually had different settings